# How do I filter arrays content date from the current date to ..?

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

```php
$personas = [
    'Joe' => [
         'date' => ['start' => '1927-10-01','end' => '2009-11-24'],
         'statement' => 'Opa'
      ],
    'Pam' => [
         'date' => ['start' => '1975-06-21','end' => ''], // empty means infinite
    'statement' => 'Mother'
      ],
    'Sara' => [
         'date' => ['start' => '2020-01-01','end' => '2020-11-12'],
         'statement' => 'cam on baby'
      ],
    'Karl' => [
         'date' => ['start' => '2019-11-11','end' => '2019-11-12'],
         'statement' => 'fresh'
      ],
],
```

## Take only the person which in the current period#

*(actual date is 2019-11-11)*

```php
$actualDate = date("Y-m-d");
foreach($personas as $date => $person) {
 if ($person['date']['start'] >= $startDate  &&  $person['date']['end'] <= $endDate){
  echo $person.': '.$person['statement']'<br>';
  }
}
```

**expected:**
Pam: Mother
Karl: fresh

Comment: In your array, the `end` sometimes comes after the `start` (which makes sense), but sometimes the `end` is _before_ start? What does those dates actually mean?

Comment: Why Sara is not in expected result, as her range contains current date?

Comment: Sorry. Have now fixed date error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things - your test is using fields that are not defined, I assume you wanted to calculate it against the actual date field (`$actualDate`).  I've also added a clause that the end date matches if the end date in the record is `empty()` or `>=` the current date (I've also changed the output slightly).

The other thing is that your data is wrong for `Karl` to be output, 
I assume you meant the data to have an end date of `'2019-11-12'`...

```
'Karl' => [
    'date' => ['start' => '2019-11-11','end' => '2019-11-12'],
    'statement' => 'fresh'
],
```

And the code...

```
$actualDate = date("Y-m-d");
foreach($personas as $name => $person) {
    if ($person['date']['start'] <= $actualDate  &&  
            (empty($person['date']['end']) || $person['date']['end'] >= $actualDate )){
        echo $name.': '.$person['statement'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```